# Is there a PowerShell approach to create links and copy those links into another library?

Tags: document, libraries

Gentlefolk;

Forgive this very newbie question - and I tried to post this question a few days ago, but apparently there was a hiccup and it did not appear. If I am violating some standard here, please blame it on my ignorance and let me know of my indiscretion.

I have fallen heir to a very folder-intensive Sharepoint document site, with many subfolders. The content has not been metatagged.

I figure the best way to make this site usable is to include metatags for all the content. This will take time, but is doable.

BUT, I also understand that Sharepoint search is flaky in a very layered environment, which is what I have.

So I thought it might make sense to copy all document hyperlinks to a new library, and tag *those* links and use that one library as the search library, so all content is flat.

My questions then:
1: is this approach reasonable - will it do what I want to do, that is have a robust, searchable document environment, and

2: is there an automagical way I can have SharePoint poll through this content, create links to the documents, and copy these links into another library?

Thanks all!

Don

Answer (score 0):

Don,

You could do an initial copy of the data to a new library using PowerShell.

Any new entries would need an Event Receiver to fire off so that it copies that new item to the 2nd library you speak of.

Jim

Comment: Would this involve duplicating the content? I don't want the content duplication, I just want essentially an index or table of contents structure I can use for sorting by tagging. 

Thx!

Comment: Any Content/metadata columns that you plan on indexing for search, would need to be copied.